# statement of creating an object without using new operator in c++ is treated as a variable declaration statement or a function call statement?

Tags: c++

Suppose Iam creating an object for a class named 'MyClass' as follows

MyClass obj1;

above statement is treated as a variable declaration statement or a function call statement as a default constructor invocation.

Answer (score 1):

It's `object-declaration`, which is initialized by call to `default-constructor`.

Comment: How both object declaration and call to default constructor can be done in one statement?

Comment: @bvb The rules of the language say it is so, so the compilers implement it so.